# maximum recursion depth exceeded in calling asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I need to calling API till the status of a job in the response will be changed from "WAITING" to "DONE" (the job changes the status from 1 minute to 1 hour).

```
async def wait_until_job_status_done(url_api):
  async with self._session.get(url) as resp:
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    resp.raise_for_status()
    job_status_data = await resp.json()
    job_status = job_status_data["status"]
    if job_status_data["status"] == "WAITING":
      await wait_until_job_status_done(url_api)
```

This gives rise to the following error:
`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

The question:
How can I change the function from recursive to non-recursive ?
Thank you

Comment: Use a while loop?

Comment: If you’ve reached the max recursion level, then there’s probably something wrong with your code.

Comment: Agree, I'm looking for some solution how can I call status recursively and don't get the error. Can you advise?

Answer (score 0):

```
async def wait_until_job_status_done(url_api):
  async with self._session.get(url) as resp:
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    resp.raise_for_status()
    job_status_data = await resp.json()
    job_status = job_status_data["status"]
    if job_status_data["status"] == "WAITING":
      return True
    else:
      return False

while True:
   await wait_until_job_status_done(url_api)
```